# Add Shipping Email On Woocommerce Checkout And Send Email Notification

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a extra email filed on woocommerce checkout page in the shipping area and send a order copy to that email, is it possible to do?

Was trying for quit long time to solve this but couldn't find a solution. Hope anyone can help me on this

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @helgatheviking  i was going through ur method but couldn't send email notifications to the shipping email , but of course i can see the field on the shipping area

Comment: Post what you have so far. I'm travelling, but I'll take a look when I have time. In the meantime, take a look at [`get_recipient()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L268-L273) to see the filter you need to use to add additional recipients to transactional emails. Especially if you're adding and saving the new email address correctly, then this should be all you need.

Comment: @helgatheviking  So far i have used you plugin was listed [Here](https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/d2975aa4d190a5b55922) . Thanks again for your effort btw iam still a beginner on programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, I had forgotten that I posted that. Here is the complete, updated plugin. Newer versions of WooCommerce require the email recipients to be a comma-separated spring. The old version of my plugin was returning an array, which WooCommerce could not process.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Shipping Email
Plugin URI: https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/d2975aa4d190a5b55922#
Description: Add a shipping email field to checkout and notify of new orders
Version: 1.0.1
Author: Kathy Darling
Author URI: http://kathyisawesome.com
Requires at least: 4.0
Tested up to: 4.0

Copyright: © 2014 Kathy Darling.
License: GNU General Public License v3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html

*/


/**
 * The Main WC_Shipping_Email class
 **/
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Shipping_Email' ) ) :

class WC_Shipping_Email {

    /**
     * @var WC_Shipping_Email - the single instance of the class
     * @since 1.0
     */
    protected static $_instance = null;           

    /**
     * Main WC_Shipping_Email Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of WC_Shipping_Email is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @static
     * @see WC_Shipping_Email()
     * @return WC_Shipping_Email - Main instance
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Cloning is forbidden.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function __clone() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Cheatin&#8217; huh?', 'woocommerce-mix-and-match' ), '2.0' );
    }

    /**
     * Unserializing instances of this class is forbidden.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function __wakeup() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Cheatin&#8217; huh?', 'mix-and-match' ), '2.0' );
    }

    /**
     * WC_Shipping_Email Constructor
     *
     * @access public
     * @return WC_Shipping_Email
     * @since 1.0
     */

    public function __construct() { 

        $this->id = 'email';
        $this->meta = '_shipping_email';
        $this->label = __( 'Shipping Email', 'woocommerce-shipping-email' );

        // add email field to checkout
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , array( $this, 'add_shipping_fields' ) );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields' , array( $this, 'admin_shipping_fields' ) );

        // add recipient to specific emails
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order' , array( $this, 'add_recipient' ), 20, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order' , array( $this, 'add_recipient' ), 20, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_note' , array( $this, 'add_recipient' ), 20, 2 );

        // display meta key in order overview
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details' , array( $this, 'after_customer_details' ) );

        // display meta key in email
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_template_part' , array( $this, 'before_email_addresses' ), 10, 4 );

    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Plugin Functions */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /**
     * Add email to front-end shipping fields
     *
     * @var  array $fields
     * @return  array
     * @since 1.0
     */

    function add_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
        $fields['shipping_' . $this->id] = array(
            'label'         => $this->label,
            'required'      => true,
            'class'         => array( 'form-row-first' ),
            'validate'      => array( 'email' ),
        );
        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Add email to Admin Order overview
     *
     * @var  array $fields
     * @return  array
     * @since 1.0
     */

    function admin_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
        $fields[$this->id] = array(
            'label'         => $this->label
        );
        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Add recipient to emails
     *
     * @var  string $email
     * @return  string
     * @since 1.0
     */
    function add_recipient( $email, $order ) {
        $additional_email = get_post_meta( $order->id, $this->meta, true );

        if( $additional_email && is_email( $additional_email )){
            if( is_array( $email ) ){
                $email = explode( ',', $email );
                array_push( $email, $additional_email );
                $email = implode( ',', $email );
            } elseif( is_string( $email ) ){
                $email .= "," . $additional_email;
            }
        }

        return $email;
    }

    /**
     * Display meta in my-account area Order overview
     *
     * @var  object $order
     * @return  null
     * @since 1.0
     */

    public function after_customer_details( $order ){

        $value = get_post_meta( $order->id, $this->meta, true );

        if( $value ){
            echo '<dt>' . $this->label . ':</dt><dd>' . $value . '</dd>';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Display meta in my-account area Order overview
     *
     * @var  array $fields
     * @return  array
     * @since 1.0
     */

    public function before_email_addresses( $template_name, $template_path, $located, $args ){

        if( $template_name == 'emails/email-addresses.php' && isset( $args['order' ] ) && ( $value = get_post_meta( $args['order']->id, $this->meta, true ) ) ){ 

            if ( isset( $args['plain_text'] ) && $args['plain_text'] ){

                echo $this->label . ': ' . $value . "\n";

            } else {

                echo '<p><strong>' . $this->label . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';

            }

        }

    }



} //end class: do not remove or there will be no more guacamole for you

endif; // end class_exists check


/**
 * Returns the main instance of WC_Shipping_Email to prevent the need to use globals.
 *
 * @since  2.0
 * @return WooCommerce
 */
function WC_Shipping_Email() {
  return WC_Shipping_Email::instance();
}

// Launch the whole plugin
WC_Shipping_Email();
```

NB: This only sends to the shipping email for the customer_processing_order, customer_completed_order, and customer_note emails.